# Returning large amounts of data from ASP.NET Core 2.0 controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 WebApi that returns data to a JS frontend from a database. For queries that return up to 100 records I am using this pattern:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<DataSource> Get()
{
    return db.DataSources;
}
```

Now I have another kind of APIs that are supposed to return data for multiple data sources, f.e. 3 data sources and 3000 records for each. I wonder what is the recommended way to implement a controller method that returns that many data. Should I split the query into 3 separate queries? Or should I return a Dictionary of IQueryable? Is IQueryable the recommended return value here anyway? I was also wondering whether async/await would be useful here but as I understand it IQueryable is already allowing asynchronous operations.

If it is of any importance:
the JS client will display the data in a graph. So it will always wait until the entire data set is transferred!

Comment: By all means split it up. Large downloads are more susceptible to unexpected interruptions. If you do it in smaller segments then it can be easier to retry just the failed segments.

Comment: It is better to implement pagination for a large amount of data. Have a look at the example.https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1073488/Paging-in-ASP-NET-Web-API